# Android - Tracking location device realtime using Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, location, tracking

I'm trying develop application using *Google Map API*. The application will display position other device in Map if user online using my application.
For Example tracking people nearby.

What is I have to send `Latitude` and `Longitude` of each people device to my database server and in all device automatically update Marker in Map every time?

Or in *Google Map API* can handle that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement location listener like this: http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/12/25/understanding-locationlistener-android/

And in onLocationChanged method you need to send new user location to server. Then server must send gcm to all devices. Help this: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client